# What are methods of Object Class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

How to check methods defined in any class in Python. 
I am now studying Pandas and I have checked pandas documentation and python github code too.

I want to know about: DatetimeIndexResampler class. size() and count() are two methods of this class. What are the other methods defined inside this class. I have checked github and it's documentation too.

Comment: Here is the link i checked in git.
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/resample.py

Comment: size() is defined in this class, but count() is not defined in this class as per git link.